# How to discover the reason of ASP.NET application restart

Tags: asp.net

Is there a way to monitor (log) the reason for restarting of an ASP.NET application?

We now having problem with rather complex site. It's restarting during file upload. Not on every file, but on every 5th-10th for sure. We use custom VirtualPathProvider, so this could be a reason. We also have a background worker threads, and this also could be a reason. It would be great to just know the reason.

Problem occurs on XP (IIS 5.1) and Windows Server 2003 (IIS 6).

**Resolution:**

Thanks guys, we've managed to catch it. It is caused by max recompilations reached. Most likely the problem is in our VirtualPathProvider, but this is completely different question.

Summary of approaches:

1. Hack in ScottGu's blog works perfect.
2. Monitoring via machine.config is also great, but I prefer to log it into our log.
3. As it turned out, simplest solution is to check **HostingEnvironment.ShutdownReason** property in my **Application_End** method.

Comment: Please say what version of IIS you are using. I believe I've seen IIS 7 log these events in the Windows event log.

Comment: Please be more specific. At which point is it restarting?

Comment: Tested on XP and Windows Server 2003. So its IIS 5.1 and 6.

Comment: I don't know. Upload file, reload the page, see the new file thumbnail. Repeat it several times and app restarts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you looked at the logging suggestions from "[Logging ASP.NET Application Shutdown Events](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/14/433194.aspx) "?  That would be my suggestion for a way to get more information about what is happening.

Answer (score 6):

Adding or removing folders inside the applicaton folder will cause the app pool to recycle (the most likely reason in your case), along with many other things. Here's an interesting article:

http://blogs.msdn.com/johan/archive/2007/05/16/common-reasons-why-your-application-pool-may-unexpectedly-recycle.aspx

on the same site is some good hints on how to monitor the restarts which is what you were actually asking. The choices are web.config and EventViewer or Performance Monitor.

http://blogs.msdn.com/johan/archive/2008/02/18/monitoring-application-pool-and-application-restarts.aspx

Comment: I know. But we don't write anything into a bin directory. Configs are also untouched. We also have very little number of .aspx pages and they are not changed. In fact this is web application - old fashioned approach when you compile everything into bin directory. (But this is not *precompiled site*).

Comment: Yeah, but where do your uploaded files go? Do you create user folders or anything? Is it inside the ROOT of the app? e.g. C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myapp

Comment: Added some more info for you to find out what might be happening.

Answer (score 2):

[Tess Ferrandez](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/tess/), ASP.NET Escalation Engineer has a good blog with all sorts of tips and tricks for debuging ASP.NET applications.

The posts you're particularly interested in are:

- [ASP.NET Case Study: Lost session variables and appdomain recycles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/tess/asp-net-case-study-lost-session-variables-and-appdomain-recycles)
- [Troubleshooting appdomain restarts and other issues with ETW tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/tess/troubleshooting-appdomain-restarts-and-other-issues-with-etw-tracing)

She takes you through the step involved in working out what the problem is, and how to resolve it.

Another thing to watch out for is anti-virus software scanning files under the root of the site - this could change the modified date of the file, and cause the app to recycle.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this article from the Microsoft patterns & practices developer center:

[Production Debugging for .NET Framework Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms954593.aspx)

Also see this blog entry by [Jeff Atwood](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000021.html):

[Debugging ASPNET_WP in Production](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/06/debugging-aspnet_wp-in-production.html)

Answer (score 0):

As others said check `HostingEnvironment.ShutdownReason`. if the value is `BinDirChangeOrDirectoryRename`, then some process is changing some files (create, delete, change attribute) in the application's folder.

If you can't find who is ding this, use [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) from [SysInternals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/). In my case, it was the antivirus process that was setting the files CreationTime (to their previous CreationTime!).