# Which event will be triggered when we RESTART Website from IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7, iis-8

Guess I had explained the question wrongly. Which event will be triggered when we restart Website from IIS Manager -> Sites -> Right Click on the website -> Manage Web Site -> Restart

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to discover the reason of ASP.NET application restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829392/how-to-discover-the-reason-of-asp-net-application-restart)

Comment: Please check the link above. I think what you are looking for is not what triggered `application_start` but rather what caused the application to shut down.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [ASP.NET Application Life Cycle Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms178473%28v%3Dvs.140%29)

> Application_Start: Called when the first resource (such as a page) in an ASP.NET application is requested. The Application_Start method is called only one time during the life cycle of an application. You can use this method to perform startup tasks such as loading data into the cache and initializing static values.

Accoding to above, the application pool start or recycle will trigger the Application_Start method.

So when you start,recycle the application, update some of the files in the bin folder or update the web.config, the Application_Start will be fired next time when a request comes in.

Comment: When I restarted through IIS, my operations in the Application_Start() method were not applied. When I did `Stop and Start`, Application_Start() was triggered.