# HTTP 404 error in simple test- IIS server

Tags: iis, server, http-status-code-404, windows-server-2022

I have this very elementary test working in computer A, but the same exact configuration is not working in computer B:

Using IIS, computer A is a Windows Server 2019, computer B is a Windows Server 2022

The configuration is:

- Default Website (at the usual physical path c:\inetpub\wwwroot
- At the server level, Server Certificates: there is a certificate (current, not expired)
- At the website level:

  - SSL settings: Require SS is checked. Client Certificates: Accept
  - Edit Permisions>Security: IIS_USRS has all permissions

I have an application defined in IIS called **bare** that points to a physical path d:\local\bare

I have a **test2.aspx** page in the website root folder, which has 3 lines:

```
<html> 
test2.aspx 
</html>
```

Similarly, I have a **test3.aspx** page in the bare folder which has 3 lines:

```
<html>
test3.aspx
</html>
```

In **computer A**, both the page (test2.aspx) at the website root level, and the page (test3.aspx) at the **bare** app level are served fine:

https://computerA.mycompany.com/test2.aspx

https://computerA.mycompany.com/bare/test3.aspx

However, in **computer B**, when I do the same exact tests, i.e.:

https://computerB.mycompany.com/test2.aspx

https://computerB.mycompany.com/bare/test3.aspx

the second request give me a Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /bare/test3.aspx

What could the problem be?
Each test was conducted from the computer itself.

Comment: Based on the error message, `bare` does not seem to be an IIS application on that server, but a virtual directory. You need to verify again. If you have configured it as an IIS application already and this error remains, there must be something wrong with ASP.NET runtime there, and you need ETW to help https://stackoverflow.com/a/830129/11182

Comment: Are you seeing any-sub status code with the 404? If not, try to check it in the IIS logs. Please share the screenshot of your site from the Connections pane in the IIS. For testing purposes, try to access other page from that location and see if you could see same error. It could be possible that that is some mistake in the URL. You could check and verify it. Are you trying to connect to a folder using virtual directory on another server?[Helpful Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/health-diagnostic-performance/troubleshoot-404-file-not-found-error)