# How to restart a single application under a site pool in IIS

Tags: iis, server

I have multiple applications under the "Default Web Site" pool. I can restart the entire pool from IIS Manage Website options but I have many applications under that which I don't want restarted.

How can I restart just the one because we cannot see the options to do so under each application.

[image: Example of IIS Default Website Applications]

Comment: You cannot see the options because they simply don't exist. You can only restart the site or the application pool, not individual IIS applications. But as workaround, an ASP.NET web app can be restarted by simply touching its web.config file, because ASP.NET runtime detects the change and automatically reloads the application domain.

Comment: How can I determine is the restart has happened. Would the logs say something there to indicate this?

Comment: Only ASP.NET ETW can tell, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829392/how-to-discover-the-reason-of-asp-net-application-restart

Answer (score 1):

IIS does not provide an option to restart the single app in the app pool. So from the IIS user interface it will not be possible to restart the single app.

You could try to test the workaround suggested by Lex Li may work for you.

Answer (score 0):

By default, I believe the app pool is set to restart every 1740 minute (29 hours). When I create a new application in IIS I always create a separate App Pool with the same name as the application. I then go into the App Pool > Recycling... settings and set the App Pool to recycle at 1 AM every day (choose the slowest part of the day, and if you are 24/7, let your people know to expect an outage for up to 10 minutes - typically shorter), you may need to offset your app pool restarts.